# selectize set default value for select populated by remote data

Tags: php, jquery, selectize.js

All other similar related solutions provided in previous answer are not working for me, so please would you assist?

Simply put:

Create page: select option from dropdown. The ID is saved to DB

Edit page: dropdown must default to option using the ID from DB

Code:

```
$("#vehicle_id").selectize({
    valueField: "id",
    labelField: "vehicle_model",
    searchField: "vehicle_model",
    options: [],
    create: false,
    render: {
        option: function(item, escape) {
            return "<div>" +
                        "<span class=title>" +
                            "<span class=renderline1><b>" + escape(item.vehicle_model) + "</b></span>" +
                            "<span class=renderline2>" + escape(item.vehicle_derivative) + "</span>" +
                        "</span>" +
                    "</div>";
        }
    },
    load: function(query, callback) {
        if (!query.length) return callback();
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                a: "search",
                term: query
            },
            error: function() {
                callback();
            },
            success: function(res) {
                callback(res);
            }
        });
    }
});

$("#vehicle_id")[0].selectize.setValue(165);
```

ajax.php returns:

```
[{"id":"165","vehicle_model":"KIA","vehicle_derivative":"Cerato"},{"id":"786","vehicle_model":"KIA","vehicle_derivative":"Rio"}]
```

**Question 1:**
Why is setValue not working? I understand, this populates options based on remote data. So surely, the setValue is not working, because on page load, there are no options to start with. So do I need to addOption first? But then wouldnt this mess with the actual option returned from the ajax? This is very confusing :/

**Question 2:** 
You'll notice the json returns 3 items per vehicle, ID, model, derivative.
When an item is selected, How do I set the labelField to display both model/derivative, in the same way its rendered.

Comment: No answers :(((

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1:** I think you should set value only when you have some options. You can set value after returning some options from the server.

**Answer 2:** Use `item` function in the `render` object, like you do with `option`.

Will be something like this:

```
...
render: {
    option: function (item, escape) { ... },
    item: function (item, escape) {
        return "<div>" +
                    "<span class=title>" +
                        "<span class=renderline1><b>" + escape(item.vehicle_model) + "</b></span>" +
                        "<span class=renderline2>" + escape(item.vehicle_derivative) + "</span>" +
                    "</span>" +
                "</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, I ended up going to Select2 and have solved my problem.